# Connect over serial from Perle Iolan

Tags: serial

I have a Perle Iolan connected to a server over serial.  Cat < /dev/ttyS0 and echo "show hardware" >/dev/ttyS0 from the server I'm connecting to works as well as running serial 1 -show on the Iolan showing the traffic. The problem is that I don't see how to start the connection from the Iolan. Nothing shows up when I run 'line' and I don't see any settings that would limit it from showing up. I have it enabled in set line and I have run 'save'.

EDIT: The connection is serial cable directly from the Iolan to the server. 
Ethernet->iolan ->serial cable->server

Comment: The plug is plugged into what ? computer -> iolan -> modem ? Please add detail as is, its too broad to answer

Comment: There is no modem just a serial cable between the Iolan to the serial port of the server.